# Error: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given (Python: tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Code Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog


class BirdsEye(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Hello Tkinter")
        self.geometry("480x320")
        self.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        FeatureExtractionView(self).grid(sticky=(tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S))

class FeatureExtractionView(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.object_list = ['human', 'cat']
        self.draw_widgets(parent)

    def get_object_list(self):
        return self.object_list

    def draw_widgets(self, parent):
        # Parent container to hold widgets for parameter selection
        container = ttk.LabelFrame(parent, text = "Feature Extraction Parameters")
        container.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        parent.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        parent.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        object_combo = ttk.Combobox(container, self.get_object_list())
        object_combo.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        container.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        container.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
```

Stack Trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-8f8ef2b5022b> in <module>
----> 1 app = BirdsEye()
      2 app.mainloop()

<ipython-input-141-cead3bb4d34c> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      5         self.geometry("480x320")
      6         self.resizable(width = False, height = False)
----> 7         FeatureExtractionView(self).grid(sticky=(tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S))

<ipython-input-143-b47db92b9d00> in __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
      6         self.parent = parent
      7         self.object_list = ['human', 'cat']
----> 8         self.draw_widgets(parent)
      9 
     10     def get_object_list(self):

<ipython-input-143-b47db92b9d00> in draw_widgets(self, parent)
     18         parent.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
     19 
---> 20         object_combo = ttk.Combobox(container, self.get_object_list())
     21         object_combo.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
     22         container.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)

TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I'm making a small UI for a college project. The view needs to have a combobox with a list of values. I'm trying to pass the member variable object_list to the combobox in a LabelFrame widget through a _getter method. However, it is not working. Also, if anyone has good resources for tkinter, kindly provide the same.

Update:
  Added the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the values of the combobox with the `values` option:

```
object_combo = ttk.Combobox(container, values=self.get_object_list())
```